# userobjs cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

I am getting this error.Return type is mismatched

```
public List<EmpRecord> Empdata(String uname) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Inside into service class2");

     try {
             @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
           List<EmpRecord> userObjs = hibernateTemplate.find("from EmpRecord u  where u.uname=? ",uname);

             if(userObjs.size() != 0) {
                     System.out.println(" Employee Name : " + userObjs.get(0).getEmpName());

             }
         return userobjs;
```

Comment: I don't see any error, just code... can you put the error in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `return userobjs;` to return `return userObjs;`

I would also change `if(userObjs.size() != 0)` to `if(userObjs!=null && userObjs.size() != 0)` for safety reason.

Comment: or if(userObjs!=null && !userObjs.isEmpty()) ?

Answer (score 2):

Typing error. Thats all there is to it. Use a capital O in userObjs in the return statement